# Why is this declaration of a function in template class invalid?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, types

Consider the following code:

```
template<int X, int Y>
struct S
{
    typedef int func(int,float) const;
};

template<int X>
struct D : public S<X,6>
{
    typename S<X,6>::func func;
};
template<int X>
int D<X>::func(int,float) const
{
    return 1;
}
//----------------
struct W : public S<7,8>
{
    S<7,8>::func func;
};
int W::func(int,float) const
{
    return 2;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    W w;
    std::cout << w.func(1,4.3) << "\n";
    D<3> d;
    std::cout << d.func(1,4.3) << "\n";
}
```

If I comment out the code declaring class `D` and `D::func()` as well as the corresponding lines in `main()`, the code compiles normally, and I see `2` in output, as expected.

But when I make the derived class template (adding `typename` before function declaration, as `S<X.6>` is a dependent scope), I get the following errors:

```
test.cpp:13:27: error: no ‘int D<X>::func(int, float) const’ member function declared in class ‘D<X>’
 int D<X>::func(int,float) const
                           ^
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct D<3>’:
test.cpp:32:10:   required from here
test.cpp:10:27: error: field ‘D<3>::func’ invalidly declared function type
     typename S<X,6>::func func;
                           ^
```

- Why can't I declare `func` in a template derived class, while in non-template class it's OK?
- What exactly is "invalidly declared function type"? what is invalid here?

Comment: I have a feeling that this is technically valid by [dcl.fct]/10 in the spec, but declaring a function with a dependent typedef is like a corner case of a corner case: I'm not sure if any compilers will handle it like you expect.

Comment: I would say that `S<X,6>` could be specialized latter, so definition of `D<X>::func` may become invalid.

Comment: @Jarod42 Looks like we need `function_typename` as well as `typename` :p

Comment: Note that using `typename S<7,6>::func func;` in `D` works ([Demo](https://ideone.com/peM7L8)).

Comment: @Jarod42 that's not really surprising, since it's mostly the same as in `W`. You don't even need `typename` in this case since `S<7,6>` isn't a dependent scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `N3337 [dcl.fct]/10:` A `typedef` of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function.

By this rule, both `D` and `W` are technically well-formed. I think the reason this doesn't compile with GCC or Clang is that declaring a function with a typedef is really rare. Declaring a function with a member typedef dependent on a template parameter is even rarer. Looks like you've just hit on a dark corner where compiler support is limited.

Funnily enough, MSVC actually [does the right thing](http://rextester.com/WFML36390) here.

Your best option is probably to find a different way to express your classes. I can't really give any directed advice without knowing more about the problem you are trying to solve, but if you ask a new question with details we can give some suggestions.

You might also think about filing a bug report for [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) and [Clang](http://llvm.org/docs/HowToSubmitABug.html).

---

Edit:

However, as Jarod42 pointed out, the dependent type could later be defined as something other than a function type, making the declaration invalid. The reason MSVC works where GCC and Clang does not is the same reason MSVC doesn't require `typename` in some places: it doesn't correctly implement two-phase lookup. Having this case fully specified would require something like `function_typename` to mark a dependent name as being a function type. I think declaring a function based on a dependent type is underspecified and inconsistent as a result of this being a very rare case.

Comment: Even `function_typename` is not enough has signature may be different than the definition (or would require a new definition for specialization).

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, it'd need to explicitly state the signature which the typedef represents, which completely destroys the whole point of doing this in the first place.

Comment: Why would this be a problem, that a specialization invalidates the declaration? Is there any assumption that the declaration is valid, which must not be broken after some point?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states : In `D` `func` is not a member function, thus you cannot provide a definition for it. It is a member with type `S<X,6>::func`.